# changed variable names causes runtime error

Tags: c, arrays, loops, runtime, overflow

I'm really confused as to why the second example is causing a runtime error when the only differences are the variable names.  Could someone please explain why this is happening?

```
int main (void)
{
    long long ccNumber;
    int ccLength;
    printf("Enter Credit Card Number: ");
    ccNumber = get_long_long();
    ccLength = (int)log10(ccNumber) + 1;
    if (ccLength != 13 && ccLength != 15 && ccLength != 16)
        printf("Invalid Card Number.\n");

    int array[ccLength];
    long long copyCcNumber = ccNumber;
    int loopCounter = 0;

    while (copyCcNumber != 0)
    {
        array[ccLength - 1 - loopCounter] = copyCcNumber % 10;
        copyCcNumber = copyCcNumber / 10;
        loopCounter++;
    }
```

**THIS**

```
    int numberArray2[ccLength/2];
    int k = 2;
    int l = 0;

    while ((ccLength - k) > -1)
    {
        numberArray2[l] = 2 * array[ccLength - k];
        k = k + 2;
    l++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**VS**

```
    int array2[ccLength/2];
    int everyOtherDigit = 2;
    int loopCounter2 = 0;

    while ((ccLength - loopCounter2) > -1)
    {
        array2[loopCounter2] = 2 * array[ccLength - everyOtherDigit];
        everyOtherDigit = everyOtherDigit + 2;
        loopCounter2++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: `while ((ccLength - loopCounter2) > -1)` should be `while ((ccLength - everyOtherDigit ) > -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you suffer from a simple copy & paste error: Inside of the while-loop you did not rename the `array` to `array2` and `while ((ccLength - loopCounter2) > -1)` should be `while ((ccLength - everyOtherDigit ) > -1)`

```
int array2[ccLength/2];
int everyOtherDigit = 2;
int loopCounter2 = 0;

while ((ccLength - everyOtherDigit) > -1)
{
    array2[loopCounter2] = 2 * array2[ccLength - everyOtherDigit];
    everyOtherDigit = everyOtherDigit + 2;
    loopCounter2++;
}
```